# Using "messagebox.showinfo" in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, messagebox

I'm trying to use messagebox.showinfo to show a message when my counter reach 4.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

global cptBalle
global cptPrise
cptBalle = 0
cptPrise = 0
cptRetrait = 0
cptManche = 1
ptsVisiteur = 0
ptsReceveur = 0
coupSurVisiteur = 0
coupSurReceveur = 0
erreurVisiteur = 0
erreurReceveur = 0
equipeAuBaton = "visiteur"



def balle():
    global cptBalle
    global cptPrise

    cptBalle += 1

    if cptBalle == 4:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Balle", message="Testtest")
        cptBalle = 0
        cptPrise = 0



def prise():
    pass

def fausse_balle():
    pass

def retrait():
    pass

def balle_passee():
    pass

def mauvais_lancer():
    pass

def sacrifice():
    pass

def simple():
    pass

def double():
    pass

def triple():
    pass

def circuit():
    pass

def atteint():
    pass

def erreur():
    pass

def creer_bouton():
    btnBalle = Button(app, text="Balle", command=balle)
    btnBalle.grid(row=1, column=0)

    btnPrise = Button(app, text="Prise", command=prise)
    btnPrise.grid(row=2, column=0)

    btnFausse_balle = Button(app, text="Fausse balle", command=fausse_balle)
    btnFausse_balle.grid(row=3, column=0)

    btnRetrait = Button(app, text="Retrait", command=retrait)
    btnRetrait.grid(row=4, column=0)

    btnBalle_passee = Button(app, text="Balle passee", command=balle_passee)
    btnBalle_passee.grid(row=5, column=0)

    btnMauvais_lancer = Button(app, text="Mauvais lancer", command=mauvais_lancer)
    btnMauvais_lancer.grid(row=6, column=0)

    btnSacrifice = Button(app, text="Sacrifice", command=sacrifice)
    btnSacrifice.grid(row=7, column=0)

    btnSimple = Button(app, text="Simple", command=simple)
    btnSimple.grid(row=8, column=0)

    btnDouble = Button(app, text="Double", command=double)
    btnDouble.grid(row=9, column=0)

    btnTriple = Button(app, text="Triple", command=triple)
    btnTriple.grid(row=10, column=0)

    btnCircuit = Button(app, text="Circuit", command=circuit)
    btnCircuit.grid(row=11, column=0)

    btnAtteint = Button(app, text="Atteint", command=atteint)
    btnAtteint.grid(row=12, column=0)

    btnErreur = Button(app, text="Erreur", command=erreur)
    btnErreur.grid(row=13, column=0)



root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Baseball!")
root.geometry("750x350")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

creer_bouton()


root.mainloop()
```

The first button "btnBalle" call the function "Balle()".

It works when I run it in Python IDLE but when I use PyCharm, it doesn't.

Comment: HOw are you running it? My guess is if you are running it over and over in IDLE session the variable `i` is preserved. If you are hitting run in PyCharm I believe it will start a interpreter each time so the value of `i` will be reset to 0.

Comment: With the Python 3.x debugger. Only have one running at a time.

Comment: Please give us  [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of making us guess at what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: There you go. Gave you a sample of my real code.

Comment: No, that sample isn't any different at all. When you run that, it just sets a variable to 0, defines a function that never gets called, and exists. Please read the linked help.

Comment: Last call, here's my full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously that's not your whole program, but… let's assume your real program is calling `Test()` multiple times, but isn't actually starting the Tk runloop anywhere, or even creating a top-level `Tk` object. So, any Tkinter windows you try to display will never show up. (Actually, on some platforms, like OS X, it *will* show up—but it shouldn't, and if it doesn't on your platform, that's not a bug.)

Why does it work in IDLE? Because IDLE itself is written in Tkinter, and the tricks it uses to allow you to use the interactive interpreter while you've got a GUI program running also allow you to get away with this. That's not something you should rely on.

Comment: Guess it would work if you're more advanced. Didn't understand everything, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when attempting to use the messagebox class.

The basis of the code was:

```
import tkinter as tk

tk.messagebox.showinfo( --- )
```

I resolved the issue by adding:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

and then calling:

```
messagebox.showinfo( --- )
```

Hope this helps.